# Sharepoint 2010 explorer view users see the default.aspx page and "m" folder

Tags: 2010

Sharepoint foundation  2010 explorer view users see the default.aspx page and "m" folder
is there a way or a setting which can turn off those cause users are always curious and click on those all the time

TIA

Answer (score 1):

These pages and directories need to be browsable, so I can not think of any way you could hide them from a user who is using an explorer view, short of a completely custom implementation of WebDAV. Sorry.